# Controlling a 1000W radiant heating element with dimmers

Tags: heat, triac, dimmer

First I would like to mention that I am a stranger to electrical components and I come from a mechanical engineering background so please keep that in mind when answering my question.

I am trying to use 1000W ceramic radiant heaters to heat up an enclosed container and I would need to adjust the heat emitted by the heater frequently. In the future I would like to implement a closed-loop and use a PID but for now, I just need to be able to do the "controlling" part manually.  I found that TRIAC dimmers and typical light dimmers (with suitable wattage) could be considered for my application but I am not sure how to implement these dimmers in a circuit. I could use some help to make the circuit!

Also, please suggest other types of dimmers if you think the ones I mentioned will not be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a light dimmer for this application.

Caveats- consumer products may not be conservatively rated, so pick something industrial or over-rate it significantly.

Consumer light dimmers do not go (smoothly) all the way down to zero- they typically "snap on" to a fraction of full power. If your IR elements are not grossly over-rated that should not be a problem.

I recently did this for heating a cryogenic apparatus using a router speed control- we had to open the control and adjust the minimum power level trimpot. The control allowed manual adjustment of the power going to a bunch of industrial heaters.

If you want a measure of the power going to the heaters, it would be best to use a "true RMS" voltmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your heating element has no significant inductance. It seems obvious, but can be something subtle: For example, halogen low voltage lamps require the use of step-down transformer. Thus, for the method of **Phase Control** will be considered as an inductive load (if you do not have access to the entire box set). Also, for the temperature control of resistive heater element based on thyristors, consider the method of **Integral Cycle Control** instead of Phase Control (no lamp - no light flickering, and due to a sufficient  high thermal constant, low flutuactions on temperature). Note that this designation has nothing to do with PID control at this moment - research the subject on net. That would be simpler by not requiring the detection of mains zero crossing. I can suspect that your application can be drying wood or even a greenhouse for conformance testing. But it can be anything else. A friend of mine builds a sophisticated ink dryer for the furniture industry based on UV lamps. In these cases, the controller can become very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Heating elements (and their applications) generally react so slowly (thermal mass), that you could just switch the power on and off using a relay. This amounts to a thermostat.  Unless your box has a strong and varying cooling source, or unless you have an unusually tight temperature spec, this will work well enough.  This open loop approach (control with no sensing) could be implemented using a simple timer. Typically, this would be a 555, but of course, a microcontroller is the next choice and it's where you are going once you implement feedback control.  Triac dimmers work by switching on at some appropriate point in the AC cycle.  This means that (1) the control is never faster than 1/120 of a second, and (2) there will be noise spikes generated whether you use a relay or a triac.

Comment: I came upon this question because I too have an idea that would involve "dimming" the heater element. Of course you are right about just using a relay, except if you are actually concerned with peak power. My application involves "dumping" extra energy generated by a grid-tied solar setup, to avoid feeding it into the grid (because of local regulations and dumb prepaid meters that can't sense direction). A 150 liter water heater has 5kwh space between 55 centigrade and 85... but you need to regulate the power and balance it with your solar excess.

Comment: I wonder if you need cycle-by-cycle control for your solar output.  I also think you should build a load bank using incandescent lamps and make a big sign that says, "Free solar power / My utility makes me burn it!"  Actually, if you heat water with your excess, you can actually get some use out of that.

Comment: I know the smoothest way to do this would be to make DC first, then use a buck converter to take the voltage down, and since your water heater is purely resistive, you can just drive it at a voltage proportional to your excess solar power. But this solution feels like serious overkill. I must admit there is a lot I need to learn about these things. For example, what happens if my load is exactly balanced (zero in terms of amperage) but my power factor isn't 1... the prepaid meter reads real power, so I cannot really just balance the current to zero. Lots more research.

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice link to what you want to do!

[Heater Circuit!](http://homemadecircuitsandschematics.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-make-25-amp-1500-watts-heater.html)